# Organiser Name - Google Calendar Api shows "undefined"

Tags: google-calendar-api

In two different gsuite for business accounts I am pulling the events info from the calendar api. But in one calendar ,"Organiser name" turns up as *'undefined'* but in the other one it works perfectly. Am I missing something in the settings?I do get the organiser email id though in the response.
How do I ensure Organiser name turns up in the response?

Comment: If someone genuinely has a doubt and they aren't able to find an answer, the problem probably being a settings issue, how does one go about getting google support to notice it and help out? Implementing this for a live project and quite delayed and unsure how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Ive posted here as well. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/calendar . . Not sure if this is the way to go about it.